# Install ggplot2 from local directory

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, local

I need to download packages and install from local directory.  But I'm having trouble installing ggplot2.  I get no warning, but it seems the library is not installed.  Output is below, any suggestions?  Operating system is Windows.  After running, the directory C:...\R\win-library\3.1 contains subdirectory ggplot2-master.

```
> install.packages("C:/.../packages/ggplot2-master.zip", repos = NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘C:/.../R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

The correct action was to download the binaries instead of the source.
Note, the following command prompts for the file path:

```
install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)
```

Comment: Do you have Rttols installed as per the [instructions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset)?

Comment: @Roland, do you know if there is an option to download the binary files directly, instead of downloading the source and rebuilding?  Never mind, I see the binaries on [link]http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html. 'link'

Comment: Success.  OK, I'm a newbee.  Started down the wrong path.  I should be installing window's binaries, not source.  Had to install several dependent packages, but now the library(ggplot2) works, and I can move onto the next error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer is behind a firewall, so the install.package command does not work.  I should have downloaded the binary install, but downloaded the source by mistake.  So, the corrective action is to download the binary files.   I want to point out that in my notes on R, it clearly states to download the binary file.  Part of the joys of getting older, not remembering why I came into this room....  Also, rambling...